# Problems with Springer Nature Template and qtree

Tags: vertical-alignment, linguistics, qtree, springernature

I have a problem regarding the package qtree in combination with the Springer Nature Template. Once I put my paper in this template, the trees appear in a weird shape: the nodes appear separated, the tree image overlaps with the text. Does anyone know the solution to this issue?

```
\documentclass[referee,sn-basic]{sn-jnl}

   \usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{stmaryrd}




 \usepackage{graphicx}




 \usepackage{qtree,tree-dvips}

 \usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}

\ex. \Tree  [.A \qroof{something here}.DP [.B  C  ]]
\end{document}
```

`
[image: tree image]

In the documentation of qtree, it says:

> Qtree will not work with journal style X Any number of things could be
> going wrong, of course, but start by checking if the journal’s style
> redefines the tabular environment. Qtree makes internal calls to
> tabular, so this is a frequent source of problems. Usually the style’s
> writer has saved the original definition of \tabular under a different
> name, so all you need to do is arrange for the original definition to
> be restored during the calls to \Tree. You can define \qtreeinithook
> to carry out the necessary redefinitions. It is called at the
> beginning of each call to \Tree, with local scope (so that any
> redefinitions it makes are automatically canceled at the end of the
> call to \Tree). For example, the JNLE style (nle.sty) saves the
> standard commands to begin and end a table as \oldtabular and
> \endoldtabular, respectively, and the replacement macros result in r e
> a l l y w i d e trees.
>
> The following will restore the original definitions for calls to \Tree only. \def\qtreeinithook{\let\tabular=\oldtabular
> \let\endtabular=\endoldtabular}

However, I don't know how to find the commands in the style file of the journal to define the qtreeinithook.

Comment: You could always use standalone and \includegraphics.

Comment: It is not clear to me how to combine the standalone class with the class provided by the template. I am not sure if standalone will work with qtree.

Comment: The idea is to make a separate LaTeX document `\documentclass{standalone}\usepackage{qtree}\begin{document}\Tree [your tree here]\end{document}`, compile that into a pdf, and then use that pdf in your main document using `\documentclass{sn-jnl}\usepackage{graphicx}\usepackage{linguex}\begin{document}\ex. \includegraphics{mytree.pdf}\end{document}`.

Comment: @Marijn +1 This is the way!

Comment: Regarding `\qtreeinithook`: a partial solution is to set `\def\qtreeinithook{\singlespacing}`, this already reduces the separation between the nodes. However, the spacing is still too big, I have been trying to find which part of `sn-jnl.cls` Is responsible for this but so far no luck (it doesn't help that the class is 1700+ lines of code...)

Comment: @Marijn! This works more or less!! Thank you. I will work with this plus adding vertical spaces manually to avoid the overlapping.

Comment: I have use a modified version of your solution that works: using the package setspace, and then \def\qtreeinithook{\setstretch{0.75}}. This makes the trees more compact. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two things going on here. As noted in the comments, the `[referee]` option of the class loads `setspace` and sets the spacing to `\doublespacing`. But the class also redefines `\raggedright` which results in extra space being inserted above node labels, because the `qtree` labels are created using the `{flushleft}` environment (which is defined as a list using `\raggedright`).

The class should absolutely not have clobbered the kernel definition of `\raggedright` but since it's almost impossible to get publishers to change their class files, here's a general solution which solves at least part of the underlying problem by fixing the `{flushleft}` environment itself. This will solve your glossing problem too, since the `clgoss4e` glossing macros that `linguex` uses also uses the `{flushleft}` environment. It will also solve any similar problems with any package that uses the `{flushleft}` environment.

With the restored definition of `{flushleft}` we only need to add `\singlespacing` to the `\qtreeinithook` macro to make sure that the rest of the tree is single spaced. I've also added some extra space after trees; you can remove this if you don't need it.

```
\documentclass[referee,sn-basic]{sn-jnl}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\providecommand{\singlespacing}{}
\makeatletter
% We first create a version of the kernel \raggedright command
\DeclareRobustCommand\oldrr{%
  \let\\\@centercr\@rightskip\@flushglue \rightskip\@rightskip
  \finalhyphendemerits=\z@
  \leftskip\z@skip
  \parindent\z@}
\makeatother
% Now redefine \flushleft to use the original version
\renewcommand\flushleft{\trivlist\oldrr\item\relax}
% Add \singlespacing to trees
\newcommand\qtreeinithook{\singlespacing}
% Add some extra space after the tree 
\newcommand\qtreefinalhook{\vspace{\baselineskip}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\ex.\Tree  [.A \qroof{something here}.DP [.B  C  ]]


\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I did see the raggedright redefinition, but I didn't realize qtree was using raggedright - thanks for answering, now it doesn't bother me anymore :) The solution would be more robust if the document also loads `setspace`, because in `sn-jnl` this is only loaded if the `referee` option is active (now if you remove `referee` the MWE will give an undefined control sequence for `\singlespacing`).

Comment: @Marijn Thanks, I've updated the answer, using `\providecommand` rather than requiring `setspace` be loaded, which is cleaner.  `qtree` uses the `flushleft` environment which uses `\raggedright`. This is really a bad error in the class, since it should not be redefining such relatively low-level commands.

Comment: I also have a problem with a weird indentation in the translation line of the examples generated with the linguex package. I guess the issue is similar to the one found with qtree.

Comment: @crealp Yes, that's the same problem for sure. I can edit this question with a solution that will solve both problems. But there will continue to be issues with this class because `\raggedright` is used in all sorts of unexpected places and should absolutely not have been redefined by the class.